# How to pass variable String from this situation?

Tags: android, variables, android-asynctask

I have this three different projects. Project1(isLibrary), Project2 and Project3 set the Project1 as Library. Now, my problem is that Im sending a request to the server but I cant get to pass the String from my Project2 to Project1. Project 3 will also use Project1 and will send a different request. Any Ideas?

In my Project1, I have an TestAsyncTask Class.

```
public class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

TextView textView1[], textView2[]; 
TextView textView;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;
//It's just a sample, not a valid soap header
String string1 = "http://soapactionheaderline"; //Provides the value for the SOAPAction header line. 
//It's just a sample, not valid server
String string2 = "https://server.com"; //This is the target URL/Server that we will be connecting to.
Context context;
int resultInt;

//Constructor
public TestAsyncTask(Context cContext){
    context = cContext; //Pass Context to constructor
}

//Getter for LinearLayout.
public LinearLayout getLinearLayout(){
    return linearLayout;
}
//Setter for LinearLayout.
public void setLinearLayout(LinearLayout lLinearLayout){
    this.linearLayout = lLinearLayout;
}

//Getter for String.
public String getString(){
    return string2;
}
//Setter for String.
public void setString(String sString){
    this.string2 = sString;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aServerConnectionString) {

String resultString = null; 

try {

    // Uses URL and HttpURLConnection for server connection.
    URL uRL = new URL(string2); 
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uRL.openConnection(); 
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); 
    httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false); 
    httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); 

    //.addRequestProperty - Adds the given property to the request SOAPAction header
    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("SOAPAction", string1); 
    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
    httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + "THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PASS THE STRING VARIABLE FROM MY Project2".length()); 
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME); 

    // Using OutputStream and Writer to send a request to the server.
    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(); 
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream); 
    writer.write("THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PASS THE STRING VARIABLE FROM MY Project2"); 
    writer.flush(); 
    writer.close(); 

    // Using InputStream to get the response of the request from the server.
    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); 
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
    ByteArrayBuffer byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(50); 

    int aint = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode(); 

    while ((aint = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
        byteArrayBuffer.append(aint); //Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read.
    }

    resultString = new String(byteArrayBuffer.toByteArray()); 

    // Use SAXParser(Simple API for XML) to handle the parsing of XML(Response). 
    SAXParserFactory sAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
    SAXParser sAXParser = sAXParserFactory.newSAXParser(); 
    XMLReader xMLReader = sAXParser.getXMLReader(); 
    // Create handler to handle XML Tags
    TestXMLHandler xMLHandler = new TestXMLHandler(); 
    xMLReader.setContentHandler(xMLHandler); 
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(resultString)); 
    xMLReader.parse(inputSource); 

    } catch (Exception exception) {
    resultString = exception.getMessage(); in the created String and display it to UI.
    }
    return resultString; 
}

//This step is the return-value from doInBackground.
protected void onPostExecute(String aReturnValueString) {

    // Create an object/instance of GBData Class and get results from GBXMLHandler. 
    TestGetterSetter data = TestXMLHandler.testdata; 

    int sizeInt = data.getOperatorName().size();

    textView1 = new TextView[sizeInt];  
    textView2 = new TextView[sizeInt]; 

    //The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values.
    for (resultInt = 0; resultInt < sizeInt; resultInt++) {

    textView1[resultInt] = new TextView(context.getApplicationContext()); 
    textView1[resultInt].setText("OperatorName = " + data.getOperatorName().get(resultInt)); 
    linearLayout.addView(textView1[resultInt]); 

    textView2[resultInt] = new TextView(context.getApplicationContext()); 
    textView2[resultInt].setText("type = " + data.getType().get(resultInt)); 
    linearLayout.addView(textView2[resultInt]);

    }
}
}
```

In my Project2, I have TestActivity1 class which extends the activity, it's the UI

```
public class TestActivity1 extends Activity{

    TestAsyncTask asyncTask = new TestAsyncTask(this);

    //This is just a sample soap
    String requestString = "<soapenv---------------------------------------------------------------->";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle aBundle) {
        super.onCreate(aBundle);            

        asyncTask.execute(asyncTask.getString());

        LinearLayout linearLayout = asyncTask.getLinearLayout();
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
        linearLayout.setOrientation(1); 
        asyncTask.setLinearLayout(linearLayout); 

        // Set the ContentView to layout for display
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to prepare your layout in AsyncTask?

Comment: sorry, can't understand your question. thank you for the reply. Can you help me with this one? I need to pass the variable from my activity to the asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really know what you are trying to achieve in your code. Anyhow, come to the problem, I think you are already passing a string value to your AsyncTask. All you need to do is to make use of it in its **doInBackground** method. For example:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... aServerConnectionString) {
   String yourValue = aServerConnectionString[0];

   ...
   ...
   ...

   writer.write(yourValue);  //pass your value to writer

   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

P.S. I believe your code will not run as it doesn't seem logical at certain places

Comment: What Im trying to achieve is to Reuse the TestAsyncTask Class, I have two Android Projects that will send a different request to a server but will use the same AsyncTask format.

Comment: but then why are you involving your Activity's layout inside?

Comment: In my Activity is the request that I will send, I can simply put the String in the TestAsyncTask class and edit the lines httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + "THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PASS THE STRING VARIABLE FROM MY Project2".length());  and writer.write("THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PASS THE STRING VARIABLE FROM MY Project2"); but what do I want to achieve that the String will need to come from the Project2, or do you have any better solution for this? thank you for your reply.

Comment: observe my code snippet, it shows how you can retrieve the value sent from your project2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think its very important that you read up on [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) because your implementation does not correctly utilize how it is designed to work. You've caused yourself more issues if I'm honest :)

To solve your problem based on your current implementation its important you see how the [execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) function works in combination with [doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29).

Execute takes a string array for its arguments, so in Project2 you could do something like this:

```
String url = "";
String request = "";
asyncTask.execute(url, request);
```

Then in your ASyncTask, the doInBackground method receives the arguments you used for the execute method. As your passing the values you require between classes, your doInBackground method could look something like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aServerConnectionString) {
String url, request;

if (aServerConnectionString[0] != null) {
    url = aServerConnectionString[0];
}

if (aServerConnectionString[1] != null) {
    request = aServerConnectionString[1];
}
```

This way your ASyncTask can remove all its string related stuff as it will rely on Project2/3 to pass through the strings.

Answer (score 0):

keep the strings in strings.xml in your library projects as well as target projects..always top priority for resources is given to targeted project..so you can reference that same id and send the staring to server without any issues